# Show MongoDB Query Result On ejs page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a router which returns a specefic user's information based on the unique Object_id from MongoDB. This works fine, and I get the correct results, but they are returned on a "blank" page as a JSON object. I want to simply fetch the result and render them on my ejs page. Here are my route:

```
//Here are my router.js:

router.get('/user/get:id', function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(DBUri,{useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
        let dbo = db.db(DBName);
        const query = {_id: objectId(req.params.id)}
        dbo.collection("Users").find(query).toArray(function(err, resultTasks) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(resultTasks)
            db.close();
        });
    });
});


//Here are my file.ejs: 

<div class="card" v-for="post in filteredList">
     <a v-bind:href="'/user/get' + post.id">{{ post.name }}</a>
</div>
```

Im still new so I know this is properly basic. I guess I have to change the res.send to something else, but now sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over `resultTasks` in your ejs template, something like:

```
<% resultTasks.forEach((post) => { %> 
  <div class="card" v-for="post in filteredList">
     <a v-bind:href="/user/get/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.name %></a>
  </div>
<%}); %>
```

Also, you probably need to change `send` in your endpoint with

```
dbo.collection("Users").find(query).toArray(function(err, resultTasks) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.close();
    res.render('<path of your ejs file>', {
        resultTasks: resultTasks, // pass data from the server to the view
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Dario. Thanks for the help! I marked your answer as to solved my question.